# Enable huge page in alpine

Tags: alpine-linux, huge-pages

My application use dpdk

I want to run it in container based on alpine

On a centos based image part of the installation is

```
RUN yum install -y \
    libhugetlbfs.x86_64 \
    libhugetlbfs-utils
```

I don't see these package in alpine.
What should i do ?

https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages

Comment: https://github.com/ceph/dpdk/issues/2 ?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε The link you put is how to compile dpdk, not how to install hugepage libs on container ( + i tried and it doesn't work)